# jQuery: Difference b/w callback and calback() when pass as argument in a function

Tags: jquery

What is the difference when add parentheses in callback function name and pass as an argument to a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have a function expecting a boolean argument:

```js
function myFunction(myBoolArg) {
  // ...
}
```

You can call it by passing a boolean directly:

```js
myFunction(true);
```

Or you can create a variable, and pass the variable instead:

```js
var myBoolVar = true;
myFunction(myBoolVar);
```

It's actually the same with functions. Say your function now expects a function argument:

```js
function myFunction(myCallbackArg) {
  // ...
}
```

You can call it by passing a function directly:

```js
myFunction(function () {
  // callback body...
});
```

Or you can create a variable, and pass the variable instead (see the difference between [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) and [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function), as well as [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) as `this` will be lost in this case):

```js
var myCallbackVar = function () {
  // callback body...
};
myFunction(myCallbackVar);
```

---

If you append `()` though (i.e. `myFunction(myCallbackVar())`), then `myCallbackVar` will first be executed, and the returned value will be passed to `myFunction`. This is actually valid, as long as `myCallbackVar` returns a function:

```js
var myCallbackBuilder = function () {
  return function () {
    // callback body...
  }
  /*

  or:

  var myCallbackVar = function () {
    // callback body...
  };
  return myCallbackVar;

   */
};
myFunction(myCallbackBuilder());
```

Answer (score 3):

Given `function foo() { ... }`.

- The expression `foo` evaluates as a function.
- The expression `foo(optional, arguments)` evaluates as the return value of calling that function (which may or may not be a function depending on how `foo` was written).

Answer (score 2):

When `callback` is passed, you are passing a reference to the function. The invoked function gets a reference to the original function `callback`

When `callback()` is passed, you are first executing the function `callback` and then passing the return value of that function.